# Reference unbound textbox in subform on subreport

Tags: ms-access, reference, textbox, subreport, unboundid

i am trying to reference a unbound text box called gCalc that does a calculation inside of my sub-form. I'm calling it inside of a text-box of my sub-report. when i call it i get the same error but i can call other fields that are not unbound. iv tried several ways of calling it. below are my examples that failed

[Forms]![SubformN]![gCalc]

[Forms]![mainFormN]![SubformN]![gCalc]

output

```
#Name ?
```

Am i not able to reference unbound text boxes in a sub-report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference something on a subform or subreport, you need to specify you want to reference a property of the form or report itself, and not the subform control:

```
[Forms]![mainFormN]![SubformN].Form![gCalc]
```

Comment: Thank you i appreciate you showing me how to write it.